# Django REST Framework: Browser Enhancement Forms

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to enable forms to be able to send PUT and DELETE responses to the server. I'm using the ajax form library specified here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browser-enhancements/

The issue I'm running into is that the PUT and DELETE requests require CSRF token, which is not provided using the library. I keep getting CSRF token is missing or incorrect error.

How do I provide the token using the ajax form library?

Answer (score 0):

In a separate javascript file include these lines of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    });

    $('form').ajaxForm();
});
```

source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax